# Elliptical arc formulas conversion

Tags: analytic-geometry, plane-curves

I need to convert an elliptical arc from this parameterized representation:

- `(x0 y0 rx ry xar laf sf x1 y1)`, where:

  - `x0, y0` are the absolute coordinates of the initial point of the arc.
  - `rx, ry` are the radii of the ellipse (also known as its semi-major and semi-minor axes);
  - `xar` is the angle from the x-axis of the current coordinate system to the x-axis of the ellipse;
  - `laf` is the large arc flag, and is 0 if an arc spanning less than or equal to 180 degrees is chosen, or 1 if an arc spanning greater than 180 degrees is chosen;
  - `sf` is the sweep flag, and is 0 if the line joining center to arc sweeps through decreasing angles, or 1 if it sweeps through increasing angles.
  - `x1, y1` are the absolute coordinates of the final point of the arc.

to this:

- `(cx cy r a0 a1 dir)`, where:

  - `cx, cy` is the arc center;
  - `r` is the arc radius
  - `a0, a1` are the angles which the arc is drawn from angle `a0` to `a1`;
  - `dir`: is the direction of the arc sweep (I believe this one is the same as `sf` of the formula above).

Can anyone help me define the steps to convert from one representation to the other?

EDIT:

Specifically saying, I need a way to map from this parameters `(x0 y0 rx ry xar laf sf x1 y1)` to this `(cx cy r a0 a1 dir)`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community is it better now?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. By the way, Community Bot is not a person. It is only a background process that helps keep this site clean. Therefore, you are only supposed to read its comments and follow the instructions it gives if you think they are worthwhile. Replying to its comments is not necessary.

Comment: This has nothing (or, at best very little) to do with neither [elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) nor [elliptic equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_partial_differential_equation), so I edited the tags. Please refrain from using tags if you are unfamiliar with their technical meaning.

Comment: But the two things are not equivalent.  The first is part of an ellipse, and the second is part of a circle.